# JSON object is null but somehow its children are not?

Tags: sql, null, presto

I'm a bit befuddled by the following apparent contradiction:

```
select json_extract_scalar('{"json_array":[{"array_field":"1"}]}', 
                           '$.json_array') is null,
       json_extract_scalar('{"json_array":[{"array_field":"1"}]}', 
                           '$.json_array[0]') is null,
       json_extract_scalar('{"json_array":[{"array_field":"1"}]}', 
                           '$.json_array[0].array_field') is null
```

Results:

```
true  true false
```

How can it be that `json_array` is `NULL`, but suddenly when digging further, it comes back as non-null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you used `json_extract_scalar` rather than `json_extract`. `json_extract_scalar` returns a scalar (not composite like array or object) or NULL, if the target of the json path is not a scalar.

Compare these expressions. The difference is one is using `json_extract_scalar` and the other `json_extract`:

```
presto> select json_extract_scalar('{"json_array":[{"array_field":"1"}]}', '$.json_array'),
     -> json_extract('{"json_array":[{"array_field":"1"}]}', '$.json_array');
 _col0 |         _col1
-------+-----------------------
 NULL  | [{"array_field":"1"}]
(1 row)
```

Comment: thanks, i'd grown too accustomed to just using `json_extract_scalar`, i forgot about `json_extract`